# I get an error "One of parameters (value: sort_name) is not of the type MysqlColumnNameOrAlias" when trying to access most of my data

Tags: wordpress, civimember, contacts, database, mysql

Okay, I'm new at this - honestly, probably not skilled enough to be doing this, but my organization has no money, so, well, I'm it.

I installed on WordPress last year, and everything generally went well. We use the system, it does what we need. Realistically, it might be overkill (we have only about 300 contacts), but I like it.

Then, this year, I noticed that I hadn't kept up with updates.

So - back up, then update. Complete failure. Did not work at all.

Fine. Restore from backup.

So, now, I can get into the system, and using the standard searchbox from "CiviCRM Home", I can find various contacts. Myself, for example - I type in "Ashle...", and there I am. Click on my name/email, and bingo - into my profile.

BUT.

From within my profile screen, click on "Contributions" and get "Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.". Click on "Memberships", and it momentarily seems fine, but then there's a floating box in the right-hand top corner saying "One of the parameters (value: total_amount) is not of the type MysqlColumnNameOrAlias". Moments later, I get a true popup (have to click "OK" to clear) saying "DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1". Click "Groups", and I get a listing of my groups (four, in my case) - but click on one of them, and I get "Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
One of parameters (value: sort_name) is not of the type MysqlColumnNameOrAlias"

That last message is the one I get whenever I try nearly anything from the top-bar drop-down menus.

Can anyone suggest a way forward? As it is, I can access names, addresses and some basic data of any of my contacts where I *already* know their names so that I can go directly to their profile. But I can't really do anything else.

Should I try a new install? ...or do I need to try to monkey with the databases? ...or am I asking the wrong questions? I'm sorry if I'm asking a question that I should have been able to find an answer for elsewhere here on StasckExchange - I did certainly look, but I couldn't find an answer.

Thanks for any help,

Ashley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi managed to get the same issue

> One of parameters  (value: total_amount) is not of the type
> MysqlColumnNameOrAlias

I had Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 5.4

I did recently changed my PHP version to 7.4 - which is the reason for the above error message - I guess I need to upgrade my CiviCRM to latest that should fix the issue(will try and update the result)

For now I have just changed my PHP version back to 7.2 which worked alright

Hope this helps!!!